# WPF using byte[] resource as XAML image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources, arrays

How do you add a byte[] resource that's in resources.resx to an XAML image?

I need to know how to do this both from the XAML and in the C#, that's what I've been unable to find.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324567) article describes how to get an image from a resource file using C#.

To do it directly in the XAML is more difficult, however I have created  a MarkupExtension to handle just this situation: https://github.com/brschwalm/Vienna.

Note: when you say a byte[] resource, do you mean an image/icon in a resource file, or an actual byte array?

Comment: Please don't post answers that are nothing more than links. If these links ever get changed your answer will become useless.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your image defined like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" ... />
```

The following will update it:

```
this.ImageSource = new BitmapImage();
this.ImageSource.BeginInit();
this.ImageSource.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
this.ImageSource.EndInit();
```